# Can I add “open in terminal” to the right-click mouse menu in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, mouse, menu, pcmanfm

In vanilla Ubuntu, there is a quite useful application called `Nautilus-open-terminal`, which allows the user to open the terminal in any folder by simply right-clicking and selecting "Open in terminal".

Lubuntu uses PCManFM, not Nautilus, so installing this program would be useless. Is there another way to achieve this right-click option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Add Open Folder as Root to PCMan File Manager's context menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444305/add-open-folder-as-root-to-pcman-file-managers-context-menu) ,
you can create `terminal.desktop` in `~/.local/share/file-manager/actions/`

And add content like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Tooltip=Open Terminal
Name=Open Terminal
Profiles=profile-one;
Icon=utilities-terminal


[X-Action-Profile profile-one]
MimeTypes=inode/directory;
Exec=deepin-terminal -w %f
Name=Default profile
```

I use Deepin Terminal so my `Exec` is `deepin-terminal -w %f`. You should change this if you use other terminal. For example, you can use `gnome-terminal --working-directory %f` for Gnome Terminal.

Comment: This is the real answer to the main question! :) Sidenote: to make this come to effect, you have to **first, close all opened file managers!**, then run fresh new file manager and it will be there :) Also you can add the path to the Name too, like `Name=Open Terminal in %f`

Comment: And for x-termial  Exec whould be: `x-terminal-emulator --working-directory=%f`

Answer (score 14):

Well, given that Lubuntu is thought of as a "lighter" distro, we'll find quite a few favorite features totally missing or not where we'd expect them to be. In this specific case, if you navigate to a particular folder in PCManFM, please press `F4` to open a terminal in the current folder.  (You can see the `F4` option and others such as "Open Current Folder as Root" in the `Menu`, `Tools` dropdown of PCManFM.)

This doesn't mean that there isn't a way to add the "open terminal here" to PCManFM's right-click menu. But I don't know of one. Instead, I've installed Thunar, the file manager by default in Xubuntu, and that does have the option you want along with useful things like [Custom actions](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions).

Answer (score 9):

**Edit (2015-05-06):** Technically, as of when this answer was originally answered, the answer is "No, you cannot add this functionality in any way". However, this may mean I simply do not know if there is a way.

Ah, I finally noticed how PCManFM does it while watching a video review of said OS.

To open a terminal in a folder, simply move "outside" the folder, right-click on said folder, and the option to open folder in terminal will be in the right-click menu.

For example, say I want to open a terminal in my "Downloads" folder:

1. Move "outside" or "above" the folder, which in this case would be my home folder, `/home/lubuntuUsername`
2. Right-click on the "Downloads" folder
3. Select "Open in Terminal"

After following these steps, a terminal should open, with the path set as `lubuntuUsername@computerName:~/Downloads$`

Comment: This is not an answer for "Can I add “open in terminal” to the right-click mouse menu in Lubuntu?"  .. For example when you need it, when you right click on desktop its a pain.. you have to open desktop folder from navingating to / ---> home--> user name ---> desktop and rightclick

Comment: Then, arguably, the answer is "No", as far as I or the poster of the other answer knows. If someone posts a solution here that is closer to the desired effect, then I would accept it; as it stands, however, this is the best solution.

Comment: @Aravinda also, technically this answer implies that it is indeed _already_ in the right-click menu, it just has to be accessed in a different way than how other distros do it. I will revise my answer to fit the exact question I posed.

Comment: @DaimyoKirby please consider accepting [linjinzhen]'s answer, since that does add that to the right-click context menu :)

Comment: @jave.web thanks for the heads up! It's been a while since I've used PCManFM so I hadn't looked back at this question for new answer

Answer (score 4):

Out of the box functionally does not support this currently.

However you can do this in one simple key stroke <kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: +1; The OP asked for the right-click method, but I think *this is a good answer* :-)

Comment: I should state that it is not possibe.

Comment: What about the accepted answer?

Comment: Ye, you can do it, but I would describe that as "not out of the box" in that you need to edit config files without any GUI.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot access it via right click method.
Alternative approach is to:

- Go to that folder you want to open

  - click on the '**Tools**' menu.
  - There is an option to '**Open Current Folder In Terminal**'

alternatively you can go to that directory and use f4

i assume you are using PcManFM, the default FM

Comment: How is your answer any different from the top answer?